# What is the closed form of this sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometry, number-theory, summation

What is the closed form of this sum?
$$
S = \sum_{k\ge1, r>s\ge 1}\frac{1}{k^2(r^2 + s^2)^2}
$$

**Note**: Though originally posted for Pythagorean triplets, their was an flaw in the question which changed the meaning of the question and was answered accordingly. I will post [a separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404763/what-is-the-sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-square-of-hypotenuse-of-pythagorean-tri) with the original question on Pythagorean triangles.

**Update**: I have posted the related question of Pythagorean triangles in the link belwo

[What is the sum of the reciprocal of the square of hypotenuse of Pythagorean triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404763/what-is-the-sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-square-of-hypotenuse-of-pythagorean-tri)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Anything with a square root is not a Pythagorean triangle where all sides must be natural numbers.

Comment: This $S$ is an interesting sum. But it is unclear what it should have to do with the geometric explanation given in the question.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Actually I came up with this sum geometrically while wondering what values of the sum of the reciprocal of hypotenuse squares would converge to so to be fair, without the geometrical interpretation, I would have no reason to think about this sum in the first place.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha - Sorry, I was thinking just "right triangle". But that just means I picked a poor example. The problem I'm pointing out is still there. So a better example would be the triangle $(12, 16, 20)$, which is included for both $k = 1, r = 16, s = 12$ and for $k = 4, r =4, s = 3$. You need to restrict to $r, s$ being relatively prime, and one or the other should be even.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes thats a valid point.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha: Changing the nature of a question after it has been answered (especially when the original question is already non-trivial) is inconsiderate to the answerer(s). Instead, you should post a separate question (they're free!) with your new constraints. You can add links from one question to another to provide added context.

Comment: @Blue Fair point. I will post a separate question for Pythagorean triplets and make this question for the sum $S$ as defined in the original question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k^2}  \sum_{r>s\geq 1} \frac{1}{(r^2 + s^2)^2}  \\
    &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \sum_{r>s\geq 1} \frac{1}{(r^2 + s^2)^2}
\end{align*}

Note that $\frac{1}{(r^2 + s^2)^2}$ is unchanged by $\{r \mapsto -r\}$, $\{s \mapsto -s\}$, and $\{r \leftrightarrow s\}$.  Applying these symmetries, we obtain eight copies of the region $r > s \geq 1$ in the $r$-$s$ plane.  It lacks the four diagonals,
each with value $\displaystyle \sum_{s \geq 1} \frac{1}{(s^2 + s^2)^2} = \frac{\pi^4}{360}$, the four coordinate rays starting at $\pm 1$, each with value $\displaystyle \sum_{s \geq 1} \frac{1}{(0^2 + s^2)^2} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$, and the origin, which we will continue to exclude.  Placing a prime on the summation sign to indicate that we omit the origin, 
$$  \sideset{}{'}\sum_{r,s = -\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(r^2 + s^2)^2} = 8 \sum_{r > s \geq 1} \frac{1}{(r^2 + s^2)^2} + 4 \cdot \frac{\pi^4}{360} + 4 \cdot \frac{\pi^4}{90}  $$
Borwein and Borwein [1] (p. 291) (see also (38) at [Double Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html) on MathWorld) show
$$  \sideset{}{'}\sum_{r,s = -\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(r^2 + s^2)^2} = 4 \beta(2) \zeta(2) = \frac{2}{3} \pi^2 K  \text{,}  $$
where $\beta$ is [Dirichlet's Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html), $\zeta$ is the [Riemann Zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html), and $K$ is [Catalan's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Utilizing these facts, 
$$  S = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \cdot \frac{12 K \pi^2 - \pi^4}{144} = 0.1264945807\dots \text{.}  $$

[1] Borwein, Jonathan M. and Peter B. Borwein, "Pi and the AGM: A Study in Analytic Number Theory and Computational Complexity", New York: Wiley, 1987.

P.S.  Mathematica 11.3 does not evaluate the triple sum symbolically.  It numerically estimates $0.126494$, which is comfortably close to the above result.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha : Of course.  The sum would be smaller, approximately $0.11687$.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha - you also have to require that either $r$ or $s$ is even. If they are both odd, then all three sides of the triangle will be divisible by $2$, which will duplicate another triangle in the sum. IIRC, every pythagorean triple is uniquely representable by $(k(r^2-s^2), 2krs, k(r^2 + s^2))$ with $\gcd(r,s) = 1$ and one of $r,s$ even.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha : Well, I don't currently see how to do the sum with the constraint $\gcd(r,s) = 1$, nor for Paul Sinclair's more complete set of constraints "$\gcd(r,s) = 1$ and one of $r,s$ is even".

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha : With $\gcd(r,s) = 1$ and one of $r,s$ is even, the sum seems to be near $0.0935$ (and I don't trust the last digit).

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha : I may have an idea for the restricted sum, but it will have to wait until tomorrow.