# What is the sum of the reciprocal of the hypotenuse of Pythagorean triangles?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometry, number-theory, summation

A primitive Pythagorean triplet is a triplet $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ be where $a,b,c$ have no common factors and is generated by $a = x^2 - y^2, b = 2xy, c = x^2 + y^2$ where $x > y, \gcd(x,y) = 1$. My experimental data suggests that

> $$ \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{13} + \frac{1}{17} +
> \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{29} + \frac{1}{37} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \sim \frac{\pi}{6}\log x$$

where the summation is taken over the hypotenuse of all primitive right triangles  such that $y < x$. Can this be proved or disproved?

**Related question**: [What is the sum of the reciprocal of the square of hypotenuse of Pythagorean triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404763/what-is-the-sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-square-of-hypotenuse-of-pythagorean-tri)

Comment: Can you find a generating function for this sequence?

Comment: @Math1000 The denominator of the n-th term $a_n$ is the smallest number such that $a_n = r^2+s^2, r>s, \gcd(r,s) = 1$ and exactly one of the two numbers $r$ or $s$ is even

Comment: That is an astute observation but wasn't really what I was asking.

Comment: These numbers are the product of primes that are $1$ mod $4$ so something along those lines may work